# Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider after upgrading to 0.60.5 react native

Tags: android, react-native

I was upgrade my react-native to version `0.60.5`
but my app is crashing when open with this error:

`09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689): Process: com.vit, PID: 15689
 09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vit-jgrJHorEudfCkM-QiDi6oQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.vit-jgrJHorEudfCkM-QiDi6oQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.vit-jgrJHorEudfCkM-QiDi6oQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6575)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6127)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6037)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vit-jgrJHorEudfCkM-QiDi6oQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.vit-jgrJHorEudfCkM-QiDi6oQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.vit-jgrJHorEudfCkM-QiDi6oQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
09-05 14:09:03.791 E/AndroidRuntime(15689):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6560)`

I don't have `<provider>` in my manifest file.

I'm attaching my manifest file and my build gradel files:

manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.vit"
android:versionCode="16"
android:versionName="2.4.1">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
  android:appComponentFactory="whateverString">
 <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.MessagingService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
 </intent-filter>
 </service>

 <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.InstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
        <meta-data
      android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
      android:value="x"
  />
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <service
    android:name=".FirebaseServices.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"android:value="my_default_channel"/>
  <service
    android:name=".FirebaseServices.FirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

my build Gradle file in app:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

buildscript {
repositories {
 maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
 classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
 }
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
 maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
   }
  import com.android.build.OutputFile

 project.ext.react = [
 entryFile: "index.js",
 enableHermes: true
   ]

  apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
 compileSdkVersion 28
 buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
 dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.vit"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 16
    versionName "2.4.1"
    //multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        //abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","arm64-v8a", "x86","x86_64"
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","x86"
    }
      }
  signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
     }
    }
    splits {
       abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
     }
   }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"),         "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
 }

dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-orientation')
compile project(':react-native-device-information')
compile project(':react-native-ble-manager')
compile project(':react-native-fabric')
compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
compile project(':react-native-config')
implementation project(':react-native-picker')
implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
implementation project(':react-native-svg')
implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
implementation project(':react-native-spinkit')
implementation(project(':react-native-push-notification')) {
exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
 }
implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
implementation project(':react-native-config')
implementation project(':react-native-picker-module')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0") {
force = true
 }
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0") 
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
     transitive = true;
}

}


 task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
 from configurations.compile
 into 'libs'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my build gradle in the root:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1'
   }
   }


allprojects {
repositories {
            // Add jitpack repository (added by react-native-spinkit)
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }

   }
}

ext {
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
oreoEXPERIMENTAL = "yes"
   }

subprojects {
 afterEvaluate {project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 28
            buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
        }
     }
  }
 }
```

I'm not working with android studio because my app is running on iOS too.

I have seen solution which talk about the  in then manifest but I don't have it in my project.

Any solution or suggestion will be welcome, I had been trying to solve this issue in the last day but nothing comes up.

Thank you!

Comment: someone has an idea?

Comment: Try to clean your project/build folder and build it again. the `provider` will show up under the debug folder in node modulo... it works for me